# Want to display all documents if a variable is passed blank or null in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema, mongo-shell

Following is my data in `People` Collection

```
{
  name : 'John Doe',
  gender : 'male'
},
{
  name : 'Emma',
   gender : 'female'
}
{
  name : 'Mr. Smith',
  gender : 'male'
}
```

If I run a query as below with

```
`variable = male`

`people.aggregate.([
 {
   $match : {
      gender : variable
  }
 }
])`
```

then all the documents with `variable = male` will be displayed, the same goes for female.

But if a condition comes like I have to display both `genders` , `Male` and `Female` and I also don't want to write another query and variable passes `blank` or `null` value then how should i display all documents with `male` and `female` in that scenario.

I am using moongoose library in backend.
And for some reason I dont want to use `.find()`

Comment: `{$gt: ''}` will match both `'male'` and `female`

Comment: So If  `{$gt : 'male'} ` then all the type `male` documents will be comming ?

Comment: How are the query criteria being determined?

Comment: query criteria are based of the on api like `api/male` => `should show all males` , `api/` => 'should show males and females'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object passed to the `$match` stage or `find` method can be constructed ahead of time, which you can build conditionally based on variable content

```
var query = {};
if (variable) {
  query.gender=variable
}
people.aggregate.([
 {
   $match : query
 }
])
```